# php не работает "Hello world" на локальному сервере

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не вставляется php скрипт в html файл.А так php работает, если разширения .php

Comment: что значит "не вставляется"? вы может сохранять забываете, потому и не вставляется

Comment: Нет,я сохранил))

Comment: сохранили, а на сервер не залили, либо залили, но не на тот, на котором смотрите, либо на тот, не другой файл. Я же четкий вопрос задал - что значит "не вставляется"?. Я уже три причины "невставления" придумал, могу еще тысячу придумать, но они вам не помогут, если я и другие не будем знать что именно у вас не так. Вангую, что сейчас у вас просто веб-сервер не настроен (`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html`)

Comment: @ВОРОН веб-сервер не настроен , но почему то .php работает .html не работает.

Comment: Вставьте код как код. Картинка с кодом кодом не считается.

Answer (score 2):

по умолчанию php в html файле не выполняется, как настроить [читайте](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-php-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8.17063/)

Нужно добавить в файл *.htaccess* или в конфиг апача такую строку

```
# Разрешаем исполнять php в .htm и .html файлах
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

После этого php будет выполняться в html файлах, что приведет к потере производительности, так как все HTML файлы будут обрабатываться как PHP-код. Поэтому php код размещайте в *.php* шаблонах.

И тег `html` в последней строке вашего кода измените на закрывающий.

Comment: уберите ссылку и какая польза от вашего вопроса останется? ответ должен быть в ответе, а ссылка - это дополнительный источник

Comment: @BOPOH "ответ должен быть в ответе" - сильно сказано, "уберите ссылку" - с какой стати убирать  ссылку на решение вопроса?

Comment: @vadim-kot ссылки на SO не приветствуются из-за возможности исчезновения или временного прокисания источника через какое-то время.

Comment: @BOPOH что такое SO?

Comment: stack overflow.

Comment: сделал все как Вы говорили,но лучше не стало.В консоли весь пшп стает комментом

Comment: В какой консоли и почему у вас в коде в конце строки (там где echo) нету точки с запятой?

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно закрыли  тэг html, должно быть `</html>`

Настройки в конечном итоге состоят в том, чтобы расширение `html` выполняло функции `php` - потому что надо отправлять файл на сервер для замены php-вставок конструкциями html.

Comment: исправил на </html> все равно не работает